# Loop through an object of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach, iterator

There is an object containing objects having this form:

```
bigObject: {
    "a - values": { atr: true}
    "a - items": { atr: true}
    "a - others": { atr: false}
    "b - values": { atr: true}
    "b - items": { atr: true}
    "b - others": { atr: false}
    "c - values": { atr: false}
    "c - items": { atr: true}
    "c - others": { atr: false}
}
```

I use this object inside a function to check every time one of the attributes had changed its boolean value: `onButtonClicked(item)`

it does something like:

```
onButtonClicked(item) {
    bigObject[item.id].atr= !bigObject[item.id].atr;
}
```

Inside this function, I want to split them in order to be able to check the values for objects starting with `a`, `b` and `c` separately. For that I did: `const toCheck = item.id.split("-")[0];`

this works fine, it will take only the objects starting with a if that one was clicked.

the next step is to check if there are both `true` and `false` attributes for a specific letter.

For this I tried to do it like:

```
let countFalse = 0;
let countTrue = 0;

 bigObject.forEach(x => {
    if ((x.split("-")[0]) === toCheck) {
        if (x.atr) {
            countTrue++;
        } else countFalse++;
    }
    if (countTrue && countFalse) {
        console.log("has both true and false attributes");
    } else console.log("nope");
 });
```

So I'm splitting the original name to get rid of (values, items, others) and after that I try to count the true and false attributes. If there are both of them, show a message telling that otherwise, no.

Something is wrong but I don't understand what. Any ideas?

Comment: where do you get `forEach` from?

Comment: @NinaScholz modified it

Comment: Shouldn't the final if statement be outside the loop. What output are you getting?

Comment: the error I get is `bigObject.forEach is not a function`

Comment: You get that error because `forEach` is for arrays not object literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the entries with splitting by `' - '` instead of `'-'`.

```js
var bigObject = { "a - values": { atr: true }, "a - items": { atr: true }, "a - others": { atr: false }, "b - values": { atr: true }, "b - items": { atr: true }, "b - others": { atr: false }, "c - values": { atr: false }, "c - items": { atr: true }, "c - others": { atr: false } },
    countFalse = 0,
    countTrue = 0,
    toCheck = 'a';

Object.entries(bigObject).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (k.split(" - ")[0] !== toCheck) {
        return;
    }
    if (v.atr) {
        countTrue++;
    } else {
        countFalse++;
    }
});
if (countTrue && countFalse) {
    console.log("has both true and false attributes");
} else {
    console.log("nope");
}
```

A more compact version with an object for counting.

```js
var object = { "a - values": { atr: true }, "a - items": { atr: true }, "a - others": { atr: false }, "b - values": { atr: true }, "b - items": { atr: true }, "b - others": { atr: false }, "c - values": { atr: false }, "c - items": { atr: true }, "c - others": { atr: false } },
    count = { false: 0, true: 0 },
    toCheck = 'a';

Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, { atr }]) => count[atr] += k.startsWith(toCheck));

if (count.true && count.false) {
    console.log("has both true and false attributes");
} else {
    console.log("nope");
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: @VigneshRaja, arrow functions are not supported as well, but op is using it, beside `let`. => ES6

Comment: The first version doesn't work for me. countTrue and countFalse are 0 all the time. but the second one is good.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, forEach does not iterate over objects. I suggest you use

const bigObjectKeys = Object.keys(bigObject)

than iterate like this:

bigObjectKeys.forEach(element => {
  bigObject[element] ...})

Or use lodash forEach, it can iterate over objects.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#forEach

Answer (score 1):

Things you got wrong and to be fixed :

1. Iterate through the `keys`/`entries` of an object.
2. Split with `-`, not with `-`.
3. Check using `if`, only after you have completed iterating through all elements.

```js
var countFalse = 0;
var countTrue = 0;

var bigObject= {
    "a - values": { atr: true},
    "a - items": { atr: true},
    "a - others": { atr: false},
    "b - values": { atr: true},
    "b - items": { atr: true},
    "b - others": { atr: false},
    "c - values": { atr: false},
    "c - items": { atr: true},
    "c - others": { atr: false}
}
var toCheck = "a";
 Object.keys(bigObject).forEach(x => {
    if ((x.split(" - ")[0]) === toCheck) {
        if (bigObject[x].atr) {
            countTrue++;
        } else countFalse++;
    }
 });
 
 if (countTrue && countFalse) {
        console.log("has both true and false attributes");
    } else console.log("nope");
```

To be more efficient,

```js
var countFalse = 0, countTrue = 0;

var bigObject= {
    "a - values": { atr: true},
    "a - items": { atr: false},
    "a - others": { atr: false},
    "b - values": { atr: true},
    "b - items": { atr: true},
    "b - others": { atr: false},
    "c - values": { atr: false},
    "c - items": { atr: true},
    "c - others": { atr: false}
}

var toCheck = "a";

Object.keys(bigObject).forEach(x => {
  if ((x.split(" - ")[0] === toCheck) && !(countTrue>0 && countFalse>0))
  {
      bigObject[x].atr ? countTrue++ : countFalse++;
  }
});
if (countTrue && countFalse) {
      console.log("has both true and false attributes");
  } else console.log("nope");
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use `Array#filter` and `Array#every` on the Object entries

```js
const isMatching = (str) =>{
  const arr = Object.entries(bigObject).filter(e=> e[0].startsWith(str));
  // makes sure every entry has same `atr` as the first entry  
  return arr.every(e => e[1].atr === arr[0][1].atr);
}

['a','b','c'].forEach(s => console.log(s, isMatching(s)))
```

```html
<script>
const bigObject= {
    "a - values": { atr: true},
    "a - items": { atr: true},
    "a - others": { atr: false},
    "b - values": { atr: true},
    "b - items": { atr: true},
    "b - others": { atr: false},
    "c - values": { atr: false},
    "c - items": { atr: false},
    "c - others": { atr: false}
}
</script>
```